# Losing the expression in debugger

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression to remove some junk on a string that I am getting back from a service. The string has some phone data that I want to remove. An example string is "en-us; droid4 build/9.8.2o-72_vzw-18" . My first task is to drop the "build/" to the end of the string or to the end of word (not sure which is better in my scenario).

I ended up with:

```
var deviceRegExpr = new RegExp("\b(build\/\S*)");
```

First off, I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this. But, when I am looking at the Chrome debugger tools the regExp value is showing up as "/(build/S*)/" . I cant figure out what is happening to the \b ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `String#replace(regex, repacement)` should work:

```
var repl = "en-us; droid4 build/9.8.2o-72_vzw-18".replace(/\s*\bbuild\/.*$/, "");

//=> en-us; droid4
```